# Proving a function converges to 0

Tags: analysis

For $h \in C[-1,1]$ defined by $h(x) = (1+x)^b - 1 - bx$ for $b>1$, show that $nh(-\frac{1}{n}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

I tried expanding it as a binomial series but didn't know where to go from there.

Comment: Why it didn't work? Please consider to show us your work. Maybe we can find the mistake!

Comment: I got $n(1-\frac{1}{n})^b - 1 + b = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} {b \choose k} (-1)^k (\frac{1}{n})^{k-1}$ but wasn't sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

$$n h\left(-\frac{1}{n}\right) \ \ \ = \ \ \ \frac{(1 - 1/n)^b - 1 + b/n}{1/n}  \ \ \ = \ \ \ \frac{(1 - 1/n)^b + b/n - 1}{1/n}$$

The limit of that last expression might remind you of a derivative. Namely, the limit of the last expression on the right is equal to the limit (if it exists)

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(1 - x)^b + bx - 1}{x}$$

If this limit exists, it is the derivative of $f(x) = (1 - x)^b + bx$ evaluated at $x = 0$. The derivative of $f$ does exist everywhere on $(-1, 1)$ and is equal to $f'(x) = -b (1 - x)^{b-1} + b$. Evaluated at $x = 0$, $f'(0) =  -b + b = 0$.

Hence $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} nh(-1/n) =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{(1 - 1/n)^b + b/n - 1}{1/n} = 0$$

---

Another approach:

If you have it, use the inequality

$$1 + bx \leq (1 + x)^b$$

Comment: Doesn't this only hold if $b \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Also, for the first comment, shouldn't it be $+\frac{b}{n}$?

Comment: $h \in C[-1,1]$ so $x$ is not necessarily greater than 0. Also, I'm not seeing how the above is a derivative.

Comment: Yes, on the inequality, it would require some finessing on your part. Let me write out the derivative argument more fully.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if the derivative argument makes sense. Hopefully all the signs are straightened out.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much!